# in Jquery - DOM element uncheck the checkbox

Tags: jquery

Please let me know how to uncheck the check box from the DOM element, here is my code and DOM element, its not working.

DOM Element :-

```
<div class="s-checkboxradio-row">
   <label for="Carrier Organization Name">
     <input type="checkbox" value="2799">
   <span class="s-panel-label-text" id="Carrier Organization Name">Carrier Organization Name</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

My Jquery Code :-

```
$("input[type='checkbox' value='2799']").prop('checked',prop);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selection is wrong. Try this way:

```js
$(":checkbox[value=2799]").prop("checked",true);  // Or false whatever you want
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s-checkboxradio-row">

  <label for="Carrier Organization Name">

<input type="checkbox" value="2799">

<span class="s-panel-label-text" id="Carrier Organization Name">Carrier Organization Name</span>
                </label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#btnCheck').click(function(){
$("input[type='checkbox'][value='2799']").prop('checked',false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s-checkboxradio-row">

<label for="Carrier Organization Name">

<input type="checkbox" value="2799" checked>

<span class="s-panel-label-text" id="Carrier Organization Name">Carrier Organization Name</span>
                </label>
                
                <input type="button" id="btnCheck" value="Uncheck"/>

</div>
```

If this is your solution, please set it as Accepted Answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Please don't beg for votes/answer acceptance - it demeans you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working cause jquery can't get the correct dom element since you're using 2 attributes incorrectly. Either use one like this:

`$("input[value='2799']").prop('checked', true);`

Or this:

`$("input[type=checkbox][value=2799]").prop('checked', true);`

Answer (score 0):

You are using two attributes so it will not work. Please try below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s-checkboxradio-row">

<label for="Carrier Organization Name">

<input type="checkbox" id="chkcheckbox" value="2799" checked>

<span class="s-panel-label-text" id="Carrier Organization Name">Carrier Organization Name</span>
                </label>

<div><input type="button" id="btnchoose" value="Choose"/></div>

</div>

<script>
$('#btnchoose').click(function() {
    $('#chkcheckbox').prop('checked',false);
    alert("Name has been deselected")
})
</script>
```

If specific/fixed value into attributes then use

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][value='2799']").prop('checked',false);
```

instead of ID; otherwise give ID